# Задание стилей элементу с атрибутом data-*

Tags: css3, html5

Приветствую всех.
Подскажите, как с помощью CSS можно изменять внешний вид элементов с атрибутами data-* ?

Как, например, этому элементу задать нужный цвет фона?
<span data-text="некий_текст">содержимое</span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*[data-text="некий_текст"]{/*стили*/}
```

Comment: Благодарю)